# Does buying a heirloom reset the 500 box rule?

Tags: apex-legends

I know that probably only the devs know the answer, but still. A while ago, I bought Lifeline's Heirloom - actually, I crafted/bought Apex packs to have all 24 Halloween items which granted me the heirloom. But did this heirloom pack reset my "guaranteed heirloom in 500 packs"? Or is it still counting since my very first pack?

Comment: Two years and no answers later, a clarifying question from someone who has never obtained an Heirloom through the method described (I'm too cheap for that). When you got the Heirloom, how did that happen? Were you given Heirloom Shards to spend, an Apex Pack containing the goodies, or were they just added to your account (with or without fanfare)? I recognize you might not remember (or even still care) but the Apex Legends Wiki is a bit sparse on details here, which might be relevant.

Comment: @Izzy it was a Lifeline specific heirloom, so I got an apex pack with her drumsticks, voice line and the banner pose. When I opened it, it shined full red and gave me these items. I believe that now events just give you the shards, so when you would open it, you would still get the red shine and hype, but instead of character specific items it will be just 3 stacks of 50 heirloom shards that you may spend on the one that you like. I might be a bit wrong though, haven’t played it for over a year now

Comment: I opened shards a few weeks back and it was like you described: red shine and hype, and three stacks of 50 shards to spend. That said, once you spend the shards, IIRC you are given an Apex Pack with the goodies inside.
In any case, my intuition says that since you "earned" the Heirloom and got the goodies directly (instead of via shards), it wouldn't have reset the 500-pack counter. But, with no evidence or word from devs, this question will likely remain unasnwered in perpetuity.